# Accessing a database through a broadcastreceiver on RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, database, broadcastreceiver

When the phone is finish booting up I want to automatically re-register some alarms, based on hour, minute ++ infomation from a database.

I try to do this with a broadcastreveiver, but it won't work.
It crashes when trying to accessing the database(DB) helper class on boot up. The DB helper class works fine when accessing it through the app.

Is this possible or do I have to use some alternative solution like a service?

Answer (score 8):

You do not want to do database I/O in any manifest-registered broadcast receiver. You do not know how long it will take (based on other device activity), and your `onReceive()` method is running on the main application thread, so your time is limited and your CPU footprint is large.

Please pass control to an `IntentService` for doing the database I/O and scheduling your alarms. The `IntentService` will call your `onHandleIntent()` on a background thread, so you can take the time you need, and the service automatically goes away when `onHandleIntent()` completes.