# access db RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-broadcast

Is it possible to access my sqlite db inside the onReceive of the broadcast receiver fired after RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED ?

I saw this [Accessing a database through a broadcastreceiver on RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261577/accessing-a-database-through-a-broadcastreceiver-on-receive-boot-completed).

Any other insights ?

Comment: Commonsware's answer from that link is correct. As is Dale Wilson's answer.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier I assume when the phone restarts, and RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED is called and lets assume I fired an intentService (or a Service) that does the DB tasks. Can I access my db ? do I have the permission for so ? (as the app won't be utilized) –

Comment: you should have permission, yes, I can't see why not. But yes, from a Service or IntentService, or anything, but NOT from the BroadcastReceiver. The system only allows a very small amount of time inside a BroadcastReceiver - you must not do things inside it, only start Services / Activities etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get away with it, but the correct way to handle this is to create an IntentService that does the database access and have the broadcast receiver call startService.

Comment: Dale, I assume when the phone restarts, and RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED is called and lets assume I fired an intentService (or a Service) that does the DB tasks. Can I access my db ? do I have the permission for so ? (as the app won't be utilized)

Comment: you can give the permissions, that should be no problem.  I'm currently working on an app that can start itself with the BOOT_COMPLETED-event and it works fine.

Comment: When you say "the app won't be utilized" I am assuming you mean it won't be visible to the user.   The application itself is started automatically to create an instance of the BroadcastReceiver.  When the BroadcastReciever calls startService for an IntentService, the request is queued for a thread in the Service so the BroadcastReceiver can return immediately.  This service also runs in the  Application's process.  The user has no idea this is going on behind the scenes (unless they are a curious power user -- they can find out.)

Comment: So because the application is running, the permissions you have requested for this App via the Manifest apply.

Comment: @DaleWilson and how do you that? Any link? tutorials on the web? Thanks